# gh-pages react app css appears incorrect when deployed

Tags: css, reactjs, github-pages, web-frontend

I'm a new developer and looking for guidance.

I'd like to use a hamburger menu for nav on smaller screens and am using the following css to hide the horizontal nav bar links when the hamburger menu is open. Everything works great locally, but when I deploy to gh-pages, both the hamburger menu and horizontal nav bar links appear on smaller screens. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

**Here is my .jsx file:**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from '../../images/logo.png';
import name from '../../images/name.png';
import "./NavBar.css"

export default function NavBar() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(false)
  }

  const activeLinkClass = function(path) {
    if (location.pathname === path) { 
        return 'active-nav-links'
    } 
    else if (location.pathname.slice(0,12) === path ) {
        return 'active-nav-links'
    } 
    else if (location.pathname.slice(0,7) === path) {
        return 'active-nav-links'
    } 
    else {
        return 'nav-links'
    }
};
    return (
      <div className={`nav-container ${menuOpen ? 'menu-open' : 'menu-close'}`}>
        <div className="menu-button" onClick={toggleMenu}>
          <div className={`menu-bar ${menuOpen ? 'open' : ''}`} />
          <div className={`menu-bar ${menuOpen ? 'open' : ''}`} />
          <div className={`menu-bar ${menuOpen ? 'open' : ''}`} />
        </div>
        <div className='nav-links' id="navLogo">
          <Link to="/" onClick={closeMenu}><img src={name} /></Link>
        </div>
        <div className={activeLinkClass('/about')}>
          <Link to="/about" onClick={closeMenu}>about</Link>
        </div>
        {/* <div className={activeLinkClass('/credits')}>
          <Link to="/credits" onClick={closeMenu}>credits</Link>
        </div> */}
        <div className={activeLinkClass('/equipment')}>
          <Link to="/equipment" onClick={closeMenu}>equipment</Link>
        </div>
        <div className={activeLinkClass('/work')}>
          <Link to="/work" onClick={closeMenu}>work</Link>
        </div>
        <div className={activeLinkClass('/contact')}>
          <Link to="/contact" onClick={closeMenu}>contact</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Here is my .css file:**

```
.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 8vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid var(--primary);
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    font-size: small;

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        all: revert;
        display: none;
    }
}

.active-nav-links {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        all: revert;
    }
}

.active-nav-links > a {
    color: var(--secondary);
    font-size: larger;
    
    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        color: var(--primary);
    }
}

a > img {
    height: 300px;
}

#navLogo {
    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        height: 200px;
    }
}

a {
    color: var(--primary);
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    font-size: larger;
}

.menu-button {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        display: block;
    }
}

.menu-bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    margin: 4px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .menu-open .menu-bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  }
  
  .menu-open .menu-bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .menu-open .menu-bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  }

  .menu-open .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .menu-open {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color:  var(--secondary);
    animation: dropDown .3s ease-in;
  }

  @keyframes dropDown {
    0% {
        height: 10vh;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
    }
  }

  .menu-open > .active-nav-links {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .menu-open > .active-nav-links > a {
    color: var(--secondary);
    font-size: medium;
  }

  .menu-open > div > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: medium;
  }

  .menu-open > div:nth-child(3),
  .menu-open > div:nth-child(4),
  .menu-open > div:nth-child(5),
  .menu-open > div:nth-child(6) {
    padding: 40px;
  }
```

Here are some pictures for reference -

[Local version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ttoj.png)

[Deployed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i9Kx.png)

I've tried refactoring my css and inspecting the page to see which styles are being applied, but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking at.

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL0z4.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Update 10/13

Hello again, thanks for providing more info to your question!

Just repeating myself, your styling syntax looks fine and should work properly. However, after playing around with your repo, the problem arises. Your only problem is having multiple CSS selectors in the wrong order -- `.nav-links`

To fix it, simply move your

```scss
.nav-links {
  font-size: small;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    all: revert;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

after

```scss
.active-nav-links,
.nav-links {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

instead of before it. Or, move the media query out as its own and add `.nav-links` inside it so it looks like

```scss
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    all: revert;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

---

Both of your component file and CSS looks fine and I do not see anything wrong with anything.

My suggestion is to try build the production build locally and run the production build locally as well, see if its something wrong in your code or if `gh-pages` doesn't work properly, then decide which approach to take.

Here's how to build and host your production version of the app locally --

1. `npm build` This will create a production version of your app into a `build/` directory.
2. `serve -s build` Will start a simple server with your app that lives in the `build/` directory.

- If you don't have `serve`, run `npm i -g serve` then try again.

If all of the above works fine, then you can double check if you are using the `gh-pages` correctly by following step 7 of this documentation https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#7-push-the-react-app-to-the-github-repository

If nothing works, I would suggest providing a link to your repo so we can further help you with the challenge you are trying to overcome.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Taiwei, Thank you so much for your feedback! 

I tried building/hosting my prod version of the app locally as you suggested, and I am seeing this issue of both nav bar versions being visible when the window is resized to below 1024px.

I've also found that when viewing the site in mobile browser, desktop styles are applied despite the media querires (@media (max-width: 1024px)) that work in the desktop browser.

Here is my repo for reference: https://github.com/annakreno/scott_wietrzykowski_website

Thank you so much, I truly appreciate you sharing your expertise!

Comment: Hi @purplepizzaeater, thanks for providing more info! I have updated the answer, hope this time it will help!